# Functional having fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Given any function $0\ne f\in L^p([0,1])$, show that exists a unique function $g\in L^q([0,1])$ where $\|g\|_q=1$ and
>   $$\|f\|_p = \int_0^1 fg\lambda(dx)$$

Showing the existence of such function is trivial, simply choosing $g=sign(f)\cdot \frac{|f|^{p-1}}{\|f\|_p^{p-1}}$ gives that

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 fg & = \frac{1}{\|f\|_p^{p-1}}\int_0^1 sign(f) \cdot f \cdot |f^{p-1}|
 = \frac{1}{\|f\|_p^{p-1}}\int_0^1 |f|^{p}=
\\\\ & = \frac{\|f\|_p^p}{\|f\|^{p-1}} = \|f\|_p
\end{align}

One can also show that $g\in L^q$ and $\|g\|_q=1$ by showing that

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 |g|^q & = \frac{1}{\|f\|_p^{q(p-1)}}\int_0^1  |f^{p-1}|^q
 = \frac{1}{\|f\|_p^p}\int_0^1 |f|^{p}=1
\end{align}

I am stuck on showing the uniqueness of $g$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Suppose there is another function, call it $g'$, that satisfies the same properties.  Then what can be said of $g-g'$?  In particular, what can be said of $$\int_0^1 f(g-g')$$

Comment: @TMGallagher $\int f(g-g')$ would give zero which would imply $f(g-g')=0$ a.e *if* $f(g-g')\ge 0$ a.e, but I couldn't prove that.

Comment: Sorry---the original comment was a misreading of your statement.

Comment: Which functional has which fixed point? I don't understand the title.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro defining F(f) to be $\int fg$ would imply $F(f)=\|f\|_p$ (somewhat a fixed point)

Comment: @TMGallagher no worries :)

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I think "norming vector" for $f$ is a better nomenclature.

Comment: I don't think $g$ has to be unique, even a.e. Suppose $f$ is $0$ on $[0,1/2]$ Then $g$ and $g'$ could vary all you wanted in that region without having any effect on its integral with $f$. It would still have to satisfy $\|g\|_q = 1$, but you can shift areas back and forth without changing them. Even when $f$ is not zero anywhere, you can raise the value of g around 1 point and lower it around another without violating either condition. Two real-valued measurements is not enough to completely determine a point in an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree, I think the question itself was flawed, would instead requiring $f \ne 0$ a.e imply $g$ is unique?

Comment: No. You are still trying to get a unique answer out of a problem with infinite degrees of freedom using only two single valued measurements. You can still decrease $g$ in one region and balance that with an increase in another region, is such a way as to still meet both conditions.